# Trying to tidy up .htaccess and remove hard-coding of domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the below configurations set up in a .htaccess file.

Instead of hard-coding the domain name (domain.com), can I use the domain of the current request and prevent hard-coding of the domain name?

Also, is that safe? Hard-coding guarantees the correct domain of course, but I'm trying to think if the 'grab current domain name' method might cause other issues (especially with the first two examples below).

```
# Allow cross-domain requests
#
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(domain\.com)$" origin_is=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

# CSP
#
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; connect-src http://domain.com https://domain.com;"

# Set domain name as a variable
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=domain_name:domain.com] 

# Redirect non-secure (HTTP) traffic to secure (HTTPS)
#
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{ENV:domain_name}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `%{HTTP_HOST}` env variable which is already populated by Apache.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this secure? Can the Apache HTTP_HOST variable be relied upon? Can it be manipulated by a 3rd party?

Comment: No it cannot be manipulated. Think of it.. if HTTP_HOST is invalid they won't even hit your web server

Comment: Thanks for the help, this answers the last part, but I see no way to use a variable when setting the Content-Security-Policy. I think that may not be possible and it must be hard-coded in.

Comment: Yes `%{HTTP_HOST}` can be used in `mod_rewrite` and possibly in `mod_setenv`

Comment: Okay, thanks. Also, I need to guarantee the value does NOT include the 'www' part which this does include. Would %{SERVER_NAME} be better to use for this (As long as I set SERVER_NAME in the Virtual Host as 'domain.com'). That doesn't have the 'www' part. Is SERVER_NAME suitable and secure?

Comment: Yes if you control Apache config then `%{SERVER_NAME}` is definitely better. I suggested `%{HTTP_HOST}` because many people use shared hosting and they cannot control Apache config.